# How to run a template job only if the previous job failed in Azure DevOps?

Tags: templates, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, expression

It sounds like a very simple thing, but I've been digging around the internet for hours and can't find a working example.

I would like to have something like:

```
  - job: A
    displayName: jobA
- ${{ if eq(failed(), true) }}:
  - template: ./template.yaml
    parameters: ...
```

but it doesn't work. I've tried using an expression, using a condition and also using a job B that's in between just to pass a flag to the expression - still didn't work.

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [**Job status check functions**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#job-status-functions) seems is not available for the **`if`**, **`elseif`**, and **`else`** clauses. They are available for the **`condition`** key of each stage, each job and each task in the pipeline.

In addition, to let the template job can get the final status of **jobA**, the template job should run after **jobA**. So, you need to set the template job to depends on **jobA** using the **`dependsOn`** key on the template job.

Then in the template job, you can use the expression "**`dependencies.A.result`**" to get the status of **jobA**. This expression also is not available for the **`if`**, **`elseif`**, and **`else`** clauses.

Below is an example as reference.

```yaml
# template.yaml

parameters:
- name: dependsOnJob
  type: string

- name: jobCondition
  type: string

jobs:
- job: TB
  displayName: jobTemplate
  dependsOn: ${{ parameters.dependsOnJob }}
  condition: ${{ parameters.jobCondition }}
  steps:
  . . .
```

```yaml
# azure-pipelines.yml

stages:
- stage: S1
  jobs:
  - job: A
    displayName: jobA
    steps:
    . . .
  
  - template: template.yaml
    parameters:
      dependsOnJob: A
      jobCondition: eq(dependencies.A.result, 'failed')
```

[image]

---